# Code Not Executing as expected

Tags: arcpy, fields-attributes

This is a follow up to [Using fieldinfo.setVisible in ArcPy?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/230017/115)

I am taking an Intro to programming course and working on a project, this will be part of a larger script.

The code runs and creates a new shapefile, but the fields I am trying to hide are not hidden on export.

Any resources for additional information that would help as well?

```
import arcpy
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
arcpy.env.workspace = "C:\GIS\python"
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True

x = "New" + ".shp"
y = "New.lyr"

arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(x, "Temp")
arcpy.SaveToLayerFile_management("Temp", y, "ABSOLUTE")
arcpy.AddMessage("Layer File Successfully Created")

# List of fields to hide
# desc.OIDFieldName is the name of the 'FID' field

z = "New" + ".lyr"
a ="Final.lyr"
g = "C:\GIS\python"
desc = arcpy.Describe(z)
field_info = desc.fieldInfo
fieldsToHide = [desc.OIDFieldName, 'APN', 'Situs']

for i in range(0, field_info.count):
    if field_info.getFieldName(i) in fieldsToHide:
        field_info.setVisible(i, "HIDDEN")

arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(z, "New_Final", "", "", field_info)
arcpy.FeatureClassToShapefile_conversion("New_Final",g)
arcpy.AddMessage("Fields Hidden")
```

Comment: Note: there is *no way* to delete the FID field, it is a required field.

Comment: Thank you, are shape & FID the only required fields than?

Comment: Shapefiles must have at least one field other than FID and shape. This is a limitation of the shapefile format as the FID and shape fields are not actually stored in the .dbf file which has to have something in it. This does not apply to other formats, such as a GeoDatabase feature class

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have run your script successfully and it outputs a new shapefile with the fields removed.  Note that it will not remove a `FID` field as this is a required field in a shapefile.

I have cleaned out some unnecessary code

```
import arcpy
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
arcpy.env.workspace = r"C:\GIS\python"

x = "New.shp"
xFeatLyr = "Temp"
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(x, xFeatLyr)
desc = arcpy.Describe(xFeatLyr)

field_info = desc.fieldInfo
fieldsToHide = ['APN', 'Situs']

for i in range(0, field_info.count):
    if field_info.getFieldName(i) in fieldsToHide:
        field_info.setVisible(i, "HIDDEN")

arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(xFeatLyr, "New_Final", "", "", field_info)
arcpy.FeatureClassToShapefile_conversion("New_Final",arcpy.env.workspace)
```

Comment: Thank you Midavalo.  I learned I can export to the workspace as well., I have alot to learn